# Accented characters break when read from file

Tags: node.js, file, encoding, fs, readline

I'm trying to console.log all the lines from a files that as multiples lines with words like:

```
Mansões
Maracanã
Filadélfia
Califórnia
```

To do that I'm using readline with fs:

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(BASE_PATH + 'word.TXT', { encoding: 'utf8'})
    });

    rl.on('line', function (line) {
        console.log(line);
    });
```

But it is logging on the terminal like:

```
Mans�es
Maracan�
Filad�lfia
Calif�rnia
```

Currently using: Nest.js + readline + fs.

Comment: You might be copy paste the content of the file from the external sites. I suggest please  rewrite the text, it will not happen.

Comment: I have confirmed you code and text file on my local machine, it works fine, might be you directly copy paste from site that is a reason it might not work. Once you copy the text , paste in any text editor and then put it in the file. This will not happen..

Comment: That worked but isn't there any way to resolve this by code?

Comment: Might be this are few special characters in languages. Various types of Utf encoding used to print this characters.

Comment: In general utf-8 handles it. I don't know actual reason but yes I am sure that due to copy pase from external site it might happen. I will read and know you the reason probably

Comment: Well, seems like i got it working by using: 
input: fs.createReadStream(BASE_PATH + 'word.TXT', {encoding: 'latin1'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments above, there is 2 type of solution.
First one:

- create a new file and paste the content from the original file in a text editor
- Copy the content from the text editor into this new file.

Second one:

- using latin1 encoding `input: fs.createReadStream(BASE_PATH + 'word.TXT', {encoding: 'latin1'})`

Comment: perfect, latin1 solved my problem here: fs.createReadStream(LOCATION_FILE, { encoding: 'latin1' })